# Highlight text in HTML programmatically

Tags: python, html

I have a raw HTML file looks like this (content may change from time to time, all we know that it's a valid HTML file):

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>
            This is my paragraph
        </p>
        <div>
            another text
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

When I open it in browser, it's looks like this:
[image: Original file]

Now, I want to highlight some textual parts within this HTML file. 
Let's say that I want to highlight the text: "**World This is my paragraph another**".

Expected output:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <h1>Hello <mark>World</mark></h1>
        <p>
            <mark>This is my paragraph</mark>
        </p>
        <div>
            <mark>another</mark> text
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

[image: Expected output]

You have:

- Raw HTML file (like shown above)
- A sentence that you know for sure that appear within the textual version of the HTML. Note that this sentence can be placed within multiple HTML nodes (like in the example above. Parent nodes: h1, p and div).
- A python script script file to automate the highlighting process.

I though that Regex is good place to start looking for solution. But I got stuck as soon as I enter a scenario that the text is splited with multiple parents. What's more, another elements can be placed between the words (img's for example).

Looking for hint, where to find the solution?

Comment: Your question is **unclear** if A) you are wanting us to write the program for you, which is **too broad** (and usually frowned upon, even when narrow enough to not be too broad, as SO is not a code writing service); B) a request for us to find you a library that does this, which is a request for off- site resources, which is **off-topic: resource request**; or C) a request to debug your code, which is **off-topic: no MCVE** unless you provide everything required for debugging questions in the [help/on-topic], including a [MCVE], but you have provided no code despite having stated you did try.

Answer (score 0):

Good software for this purpose is [BeautifulSoup].[1](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) Use the `replace_with` method to replace strings or tags. Use the `new_tag` method to create a tag to put in place of an existing tag. Begin by making 'soup' of the existing HTML. There are loads of examples of manipulations involving BeautifulSoup all over the 'net.

This sample code shows how to deal with the first occurrence of 'Hello world' in your HTML.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'lxml')
>>> new_h1 = soup.new_tag('h1')
>>> new_h1.string = 'Hello '
>>> mark = soup.new_tag('mark')
>>> mark.string = 'World'
>>> mark
<mark>World</mark>
>>> new_h1.append(mark)
>>> new_h1
<h1>Hello <mark>World</mark></h1>
>>> h1 = soup.h1
>>> h1.replace_with(new_h1)
<h1>Hello World</h1>
>>> for line in soup.prettify().split('\n'):
...     line
...     
'<html>'
' <body>'
'  <h1>'
'   Hello'
'   <mark>'
'    World'
'   </mark>'
'  </h1>'
'  <p>'
'   This is my paragraph'
'  </p>'
'  <div>'
'   another text'
'  </div>'
' </body>'
'</html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I would use beautifulsoup to get all the children in the body tags (let body be the parent) after getting all the NavigableString

https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#contents this link contain more information.

You can then reconstruct the string (content) with the mark tag `<mark> Content </mark>` because you can extract the content and tag from beautiful soup and put the reconstructed string back. regex is too much pain

Or you can use do some recursion down the html tree structure (don't do that) regex is a messy solution for sure

Answer (score 0):

As a hint:

---

Step 1 : Replace all tags with % and save the replaced tag in list

```
s1 = %%%Hello World%%This is my paragraph%%%%another%text%%%    
tags = ['<HTML>','<body>,<h1>,</h1>,<p> , ...]
```

---

Step 2 : Search the regex in `s1`

```
World(\s|%)+This(\s|%)+is(\s|%)+my(\s|%)+paragraph(\s|%)+another
```

---

Step 3: Insert `<mark>` at the beginning of the match and `</mark>` in the end. for each % group insert `</mark>` before the group and `<mark>` in the end of the group.

```
%%%Hello <mark>World</mark>%%<mark>This is my paragraph</mark>%%%%<mark>another</mark>%text%%%
```

---

Step 4: Now, restore the tags from the list using the tag list.

```
<HTML><body><h1>Hello <mark>World</mark></h1><p><mark>This is my paragraph</mark></p> ...
```